# Question about server date and laravel cron jobs

Tags: php, laravel

I just learnt about cron jobs in the server and larave crons, in my  laravel apps  I set timezone in .env file like this:

```
APP_TIMEZONE='Europe/Madrid'
```

Now in my ubuntu VPS I ran the command

```
date
```

And noticed it says UTC with one hour earlier than my local time (one hour less sorry for english), Now I have two questions:

When I run a cron job from laravel using the schedule command what time does the app take into account to run the commands, my VPS time (UTC, one hour less) or my laravel app time (Europe/Madrid)?

I want to fix my VPS time so its the same as my local time (changing it to UTC+1 would fix it) , how can I change the date/timezone? Is it a good idea to do this?

Comment: I think you can use `date_default_timezone_set`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Scheduler will use the timezone specified in env file, I reckon you should keep the timezone config in the application, so you don't have to bother about it in new servers.

> from Laravel source Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php

```
/**
     * Get the timezone that should be used by default for scheduled events.
     *
     * @return \DateTimeZone|string|null
     */
    protected function scheduleTimezone()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config'];
        return $config->get('app.schedule_timezone', $config->get('app.timezone'));
    }
```

It gives priority to app.schedule_timezone and fallback to default app.timezone.

Alternative you can override this function : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#timezones